# Displaying alias name game center turn-based game

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Im making a turn-based game and I wish to display the username you are playing against in the game view.

to show your own username I can use

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] alias];
```

I was wondering If there is any easy code like this to view the connected player alias name, It's a turn-based game So I believe there is no constant connection and the name has to be send with some playing his of her turn? or is that thought not correct?

Hope someone can help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is any short easy bit of code to do this. I've run into the same problem.

The way I solved it was with the following code snippet:

```
GKTurnBasedParticipant *otherParticipant;
for (GKTurnBasedParticipant *participant in match.participants) {
    if (NO == [participant.playerID isEqualToString:[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID]) {
        otherParticipant = participant;
    }
}

if (nil != otherParticipant && nil != otherParticipant.playerID) {
    [GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:@[ otherParticipant.playerID ]
                  withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *players, NSError *error) {
                      // Here, `players` is an array of `GKPlayer`s. You can
                      // access the `displayName` or `alias` property here.
                  }];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I made a class extension.

GKTurnBasedMatchExtensions.h

```
@interface GKTurnBasedMatch (GKTurnBasedMatchExtensions)
@property(nonatomic, readonly) GKTurnBasedParticipant* opponent;
@end
```

GKTurnBasedMatchExtensions.c

```
#import "GKTurnBasedMatchExtensions.h" 

@implementation GKTurnBasedMatch (GKTurnBasedMatchExtensions)
-(GKTurnBasedParticipant*)opponent
{
  GKTurnBasedParticipant *firstPlayer = self.participants[0];
  return ([firstPlayer.playerID isEqualToString:GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer.playerID]) ? self.participants[1] : self.participants[0];
}
@end
```

and I can then do this:

```
#import "GKTurnBasedMatchExtensions.h"

match.opponent.player.alias
```